# Why is my Google Maps "Hello world?" page displaying as empty?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, boilerplate

I have the source of my page below; I tried to load Google Maps into Boilerplate 3, and am getting a blank page with no JavaScript errors. How could this be improved?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #map_canvas { height: 100%, width: 100% }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]><p class=chromeframe>Your browser is <em>ancient!</em> <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade to a different browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to experience this site.</p><![endif]-->
  <header>

  </header>
  <div role="main">

    <div id="map_canvas">
    </div>

  </div>
  <footer>

  </footer>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

  <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

<script>


function initialize()
    {
    var myoptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.881944, -87.627778),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    myoptions);


    }

function load_script()
    {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAi288X8h9Y4fXM21Q0-my6O6kiLaDeC7M&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

window.onload = load_script;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

--EDIT--

The code I cobbled together from Google's example first started on painting a map, then wiped the screen and said my key couldn't used for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAi288X8h9Y4fXM21Q0-my6O6kiLaDeC7M&sensor=true">
    </script>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();">
<script>
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
myOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src =
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: alert(), placed at the beginning and end of the jQuery.ready() function, is not working. An alert() placed after the end of jQuery.ready() is being called. Am I making a mistake in my use of jQuery.ready()?

Comment: That is not the code of Google's "Hello World example", and we cannot see the rest of the code you're loading. What's in /js/script.js?A link to a live demo page would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Define a width for the map_canvas div.

Comment: Thank you. Now "document.appendChild(script);" is giving "Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3." Any ideas for that?