# Google Maps API demo "Hello World" hangs Chrome

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The simple demo from the Google Maps API documentation page:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

hangs Chrome Version 23.0.1271.91 m (Windows XP).  There is no output.  The cursor remains stuck on hourglass-pointer.  The window is completely unresponsive and I cannot access the Developer Window to see where it might be stuck.

The page and map load and render completely in Firefox (V16.0.2) and IE8, so this is obviously not a key-related issue.

The problem looks similar to this one: [Why is my Google Maps "Hello world?" page displaying as empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228417/why-is-my-google-maps-hello-world-page-displaying-as-empty), but I have already copied the code and changed the width of the "canvas" div from "100%" to a fixed number like "500px" without any improvement.  In any case I'd be surprised if that is the problem because both the Map API and Chrome are Google products!  You'd think someone would check it!

If anyone reading this has encountered the same problem, please respond.

Answer (score 0):

Just after I posted this I updated Chrome to Version 23.0.1271.95 m, and guess what?  The demo app renders and displays the map!

So if anyone else has this problem with Chrome, see if you have the latest version and upgrade if not.  :)